# List of Dimensions and Metrics in different languages

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

The [Metadata API](https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/metadata/ga/columns?pp=1) can be used to get a list of google analytic dimensions and metrics.  Is it possible to have this list returned in different languages?  Is there a list/database of the metrics and dimensions for different languages?

Answer (score 2):

The MetaData API only returns in english there is no way to change the language.  I dont think they will be changing that anytime soon.  But you could try adding it as a feature request.  http://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/list

Comment: Good idea.  I have done it:   https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=385&colspec=ID%20Component%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary&start=200